# Calendar with color the available date

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]

It is a program to write a calendar using `DateTime` with WPF. I did not use styles.

```
public void Display()
{
   grdCalendar.Children.Clear();
   int[,] calendar = new int[Column, Row];

   try
   {
      CalendarHelper.PrintOutDate(calendar, Month, Year);
   }
   catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
   {
      Environment.Exit(0);
   }


   for (int col = 0; col < Column; col++)
   {
      for (int row = 0; row < Row; row++)
      {
         if (calendar[col, row] != 0)
         {
            Label lbl = new Label
            {
               Content = calendar[col, row],

               HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
               VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
            };

            Grid.SetColumn(lbl, row);
            Grid.SetRow(lbl, col);

            grdCalendar.Children.Add(lbl);
         }
      }
   }
}

public static void PrintOutDate(int[,] arr, int month, int year)
{
   int days = FirstDay;

   int day;
   int date;

   try
   {
      day = GetStartDayOfWeek(year, month);
      date = GetDayCount(month, year);
   }
   catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
   }

   for (int col = 0; col < Column; col++)
   {
      for (int row = 0; row < Row; row++)
      {
         if (days > date)
         {
            break;
         }

         if (col == 0)
         {
            if (day > row)
            {
               continue;
            }
         }
         arr[col, row] = days++;
      }
   }
}
```

In function `PrintOutDate`, the function `GetStartDayOfWeek` returns what day of the week is the first day (Sun(0)~Sat(6)). The function `GetDayCount` returns the date of the current month.

Then, input the increased array value in Display.

I'd like to paint Sunday with red and Saturday with blue, but I don't know how.

How can I color the date?

Comment: As a note on the code that you have posted, `Grid.SetColumn(lbl, row);` and `Grid.SetRow(lbl, col);` are wrong, as you are assigning rows to columns and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Sunday is displayed in the first column and Saturday in the last, you can check if the current column is `0` or `6` and set the `Foreground` of the `Label` to `Red` or `Blue`.

```
if (calendar[col, row] != 0)
{
   Label lbl = new Label
   {
      Content = calendar[col, row],

      HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
      VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
   };

   if (col == 0)
   {
      // It is Sunday
      lbl.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
   }
   else if (col == 6)
   {
      // It is Saturday
      lbl.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
   }

   Grid.SetColumn(lbl, col);
   Grid.SetRow(lbl, row);

   grdCalendar.Children.Add(lbl);
}
```